# CSS Framework .... are they better and which one is the best

Tags: css, css-frameworks

What is the best CSS framework out there? Also is it better to use CSS framework or use custom css ? the site  am willing to design is about 50 pages ... and I am confused whether to use css framework or built my own custom css

Comment: this is so going to be closed as not a real question

Comment: What's a CSS framework? Have I been missing out on something?

Comment: Looking at the related questions, I see a bunch of questions exactly like this one.

Comment: Try this one: http://unobtrusivecss.com/ :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a CSS framework in the same way Jquery is a Javascript Framework (a bundle of libraries to make your work easier) I think you will have to look for CSS-dynamic generated content.

The only one I know (and AFAIK the best one out there), being a Rails Developer is SASS (you can get more info on [Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/268-sass-basics). SASS is actually a 
I think it could really cut you some time.

I know there is a porting to PHP in progress ([phamlp](http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/)) but don't know its state.
Otherwise, you could install rails and use it to compile SASS obtaining CSS-formatted stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

i'd recommend [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) and [960](http://960.gs/). I've worked with both and they're equally good in the sense they make grid based layouts easier.

Having said that, I try to go custom 99% of the time because you have more control and you don't need to "hack" the framework to suit your needs.

So if you have the time, make your own framework with a good CSS reset to start with, some typography settings and layout element defaults that you think you'll use quite often.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki

Don't think there really is much of a 'framework' for css, but OOCSS is the best thing you can do for yourself and all future developers on the project.